# Scalatest GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks init seed

Tags: scala, scalatest, property-based-testing

I'm using [Scalatest 3.1.0-SNAP13](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.13/3.1.0-SNAP13) and cannot find how to specify the init seed option from this [PR](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/pull/1505).
I'm using SBT to run the test so if there is a way to specify this option in `build.sbt` would be ideal.

Answer (score 5):

The `-S` flag seems to be [disabled](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/commit/0fcc46388e575a1fc9be23500e5988de404ee9fa#diff-f5a6e2db940c38e4994a4cf86650fb8bR220) in 3.1.x:

```
parseLongArgument(seedArgs, "-S") match {
  case Some(seed) => // Randomizer.defaultSeed.getAndSet(Some(seed))
    println("Note: -S for setting the Randomizer seed is not yet supported.")
  case None => // do nothing
}
```

However it is seems to be [enabled](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/55c019d09fccaaeaf9a1e398636cca27e58d755d/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/tools/ScalaTestFramework.scala#L260) in 3.2.x, so try

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-M1" % Test
```

and

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-S", "1568769615146")
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with:

```
// specify an initial seed 0
Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-S", "0")
```

Result:

```
[info] SummaryTest:
[info] - hello *** FAILED *** (49 milliseconds)
[info]   GeneratorDrivenPropertyCheckFailedException was thrown during property evaluation. (SummaryTest.scala:8)
[info]     Falsified after 0 successful property evaluations.
[info]     Message: 0 was not greater than 1
[info]     Location: (SummaryTest.scala:10)
[info]     Occurred when passed generated values (
[info]       ""
[info]     )
[info]     Init Seed: 0
```